# VPN Connection - Android Not Working , working fine IPhone

Tags: vpn

Our company users with IPhones are able establish a VPN connection. 
Few of us have Androids me specifically has a (HTC) Android Version 5.0.1 but unable to get a VPN connection

I followed the directions and information provided by IT department but no success. Is there a log I can see on my phone to help troubleshoot why it is failing (it doesn't seem to be connecting to the ASA to view any information from there). In the directions it states "The connection should then connect and function. If it does not work, check the IPsec logs and the Status > System Logs, VPN, L2TP Raw log to see more specific errors. " I can't find this System Log??

Answer (score 3):

To see complete Android OS logs, you can easily use the `logcat` command in an ADB(Android Debug Bridge) console. There are two ways to do this: you can use the *real* adb by connecting your phone to a computer with valid adb drivers, or you can do it right on your phone by downloading a [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) and running the `logcat` command there. The live logcat will spit out a lot of data consistently, so you'll want to filter it. Use `logcat | grep (some keyword)` to filter to only lines containing the keyword.

As for your VPN problem, Android's built-in VPN service, *from my experience*, is pretty faulty. You might want to install an external VPN client off the Play Store, such as [OpenVPN Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en).

Hope this solves your mystery.

Comment: For OpenVPN Connect you need an „ovpn profile“ which my admistrator didn't give me.

Comment: And what is even worse: „OpenVPN is not compatible with IPSec, IKE, PPTP, or L2TP. “ — Not a very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but a simple solution I have found is make sure power saving mode is turned off. I looked all over the Internet to figure this out and discovered it by accident. Hope it helps someone else. I was using Betternet which is a great VPN service but it would not connect. I turned power saving mode off and it connected instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I set up in my router a VPN server, so I could do a VPN to my home when I am away. I was able to connect to my VPN using a Windows PC computer, but I was not able to connect to my VPN using my Android phone. After a lot of research I found that by turning off in my Android phone "Data Saver" mode which limits background data, my Android phone was finally able to connect to my VPN!!! So, if you have similar problem, I recommend you to turn off any "Power Saving"  mode in your phone or anything that could limit background data. 
Hope this helps, I just wanted to share with all of you how I solved my connection problem with Android.